# How do I implement DbContext inheritance for multiple databases in EF7 / .NET Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am building web APIs in ASP.NET Core 1.1.

I have a number different databases (for different systems) which have common base schemas for configuration items such as Configuration, Users and groups (about 25 tables in all).  I am trying to avoid duplicating the quite extensive EF configuration for the shared part of the model by inheriting from a base class as shown in the diagram.

[image: My DbContext inheritance tree]

However, this does not work because of the Entity Framework (EF) requirement to pass `DbContextOptions<DerivedRepository>` as a parameter to the constructor, where `DerivedRepository` must match the type of the repository the constructor is called on.  The parameter must then be passed down to the base `DbContext` by calling `:base(param)`.

So when (for example) InvestContext is initialised with `DbContextOptions<InvestContext>`, it calls `base(DbContextOptions<InvestContext>)` and EF throws an error because the call to the `ConfigurationContext` constructor is receiving a parameter of type `DbContextOptions<InvestContext>` instead of the required type `DbContextOptions<ConfigurationContext>`.  Since the options field on DbContext is defined as

```
    private readonly DbContextOptions _options;
```

I can't see a way around this.

What is the best way to define the shared model once and use it multiple times?  I guess I could create a helper function and call it from every derived context, but it's not nearly as clean or transparent as inheritance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

OK, I have got this working in a way which still uses the inheritance hierarchy, like this (using `InvestContext` from above as the example):

As stated, the InvestContext class receives a constructor parameter of type `DbContextOptions<InvestContext>`, but must pass `DbContextOptions<ConfigurationContext>` to it's base.

I have written a method which digs the connectionstring out of a `DbContextOptions` variable, and builds a DbContextOptions instance of the required type.  InvestContext uses this method to convert its options parameter to the right type before calling base().

The conversion method looks like this:

```
    protected static DbContextOptions<T> ChangeOptionsType<T>(DbContextOptions options) where T:DbContext
    {
        var sqlExt = options.Extensions.FirstOrDefault(e => e is SqlServerOptionsExtension);

        if (sqlExt == null)
            throw (new Exception("Failed to retrieve SQL connection string for base Context"));

        return new DbContextOptionsBuilder<T>()
                    .UseSqlServer(((SqlServerOptionsExtension)sqlExt).ConnectionString)
                    .Options;
    }
```

and the InvestContext constructor call changes from this:

```
  public InvestContext(DbContextOptions<InvestContext> options):base(options)
```

to this:

```
  public InvestContext(DbContextOptions<InvestContext> options):base(ChangeOptionsType<ConfigurationContext>(options))
```

So far both InvestContext and ConfigurationContext work for simple queries, but it seems like a bit of a hack and possibly not something the designers of EF7 had in mind.

I am still concerned that EF is going to get itself in a knot when I try complex queries, updates etc. *It appears that this is not a problem, see below)*

**Edit:** I've logged this problem as an issue with the EF7 team [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7533), and a team member has suggested a change to the EF Core core as follows:

> "We should update the check to allow TContext to be a type that is derived from the current context type"

This would solve the problem.

After further interaction with that team member (which you can see on the issue) and some digging through the EF Core code, the approach I've outlined above looks safe and the best approach until the suggested change is implemented.

Answer (score 96):

I would like to bring [this post from the OP's GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7533#issuecomment-353669263) to everyone's attention:

> I was able to resolve this without a hack by providing a protected constructor that uses DbContextOptions without any type. Making the second constructor protected ensures that it will not get used by DI.

```
public class MainDbContext : DbContext {
    public MainDbContext(DbContextOptions<MainDbContext> options)
        : base(options) {
    }

    protected MainDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options) {
    }
}

public class SubDbContext : MainDbContext {
    public SubDbContext (DbContextOptions<SubDbContext> options)
        : base(options) {
    }
}
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. Looks like this will be added to the official documentation as the suggested pattern in this case. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/594

Comment: This saved me after a few hours of debugging and trying different things. Works like a charm

Comment: Wow bru I spent hours on this. Thank you so much.

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer and it matches the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontextoptions-versus-dbcontextoptionstcontext).
It could still be supplemented with a note explaining what to configure in the services when starting the application.
In my opinion, one should invoke `builder.Services.AddDbContext` for each derived class.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your requirements you can simply use the non type specific version of DbContextOptions.

Change these:

```
public ConfigurationContext(DbContextOptions<ConfigurationContext> options):base(options)    
public InvestContext(DbContextOptions<InvestContext> options):base(options)
```

to this:

```
public ConfigurationContext(DbContextOptions options):base(options) 
public InvestContext(DbContextOptions options):base(options)
```

Then if you create your ConfigurationContext first, the classes that inherit it seem to get the same configuration.  It may also depend on the order in which you initialize the different contexts.

**Edit:**
My working example:

```
public class QueryContext : DbContext
{
    public QueryContext(DbContextOptions options): base(options)
    {
    }
}

public class CommandContext : QueryContext
{
    public CommandContext(DbContextOptions options): base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

And in Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<CommandContext>(options =>
                 options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

services.AddDbContext<QueryContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

alternatively, in a test class:

```
    var connectionString = "Data Source=MyDatabase;Initial Catalog=MyData;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddDbContext<QueryContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString))
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    _db = serviceProvider.GetService<QueryContext>();
```

Comment: Do you actually have code which does this, and if so what version of EF7 are you running?  Because when I try this DbContextOptions is abstract, and even if I implement a derived class (DbCo) I get the compile time error calling the constructor: "DbCo is not assignable to parameter type DbContextOptions<DerivedContext>".  Looking in the EF7 code base at the DbContext constructor, there is a check there for `options.ContextType.GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(GetType().GetTypeInfo())`, so the DbContextOptions must be a generic derivative typed as the DerivedContext.

Comment: Yes, I have this working, both from my application and in a test host configuration.  I'm using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.0`.  You may need to remove the `<DerivedContext>` from the type in the context constructor

Comment: I have edited my question, adding the details of my attempt to implement your suggestion (not enough space in a comment).  I get the error I expected, given the check I see in the EntityFramework code base.  As far as I can see, the only way to avoid that error would be to call `base()` instead of `base(options)`, which I think would lead to other problems if you are initialising multiple contexts.  Could you perhaps extend your answer with more comprehensive code sample showing DerivedContext definition and usage?  Thanks!

Comment: My examples added.  I don't see much difference, but may help.

Comment: OK, yes, I did quite a bit of fiddling with this [here](https://github.com/Ettery/AddDbContext), and it works with some serious caveats which aren't immediately obvious.  Firstly, each call to AddDbContext appears to register DbContextOptions with the DI, meaning that the last context registered will be the type of the DbContextOptions passed to *all* DbContexts whose constructors specify a non-generic parameter. Implications: all contexts get the same options (incl. connection string); context which inherist from DbContext must be registered last; *(see next comment)*

Comment: only contexts in the same inheritance tree can be instantiated - so in the above diagram you can instantiate a ConfigurationContext and InvestContext/CrmContext (provided they point to the same database) but not a context outside the tree.  Since I need to create a ConfigurationContext on one database and a CrmContext on another, and may need additional contexts, this wouldn't work for me.  Also, I think the way it's working is a bit obscure and as a result of some strange DI behaviour (IMO), so I think it's likely to cause maintenance problems down the line.  Thanks for the input, though!

Comment: Agree it's a hack and wouldn't work for many use cases.  I have managed to get 2 different connection strings to work - one real and one InMemory.  You may also find that if you need separate connection strings you need different app domains, as all DbContext that connect to the same app domain share the same connection.  Overall, it still needs to be fixed.

Comment: On that last comment about AppDomains, are you talking about DbContexts which inherit from each other specifically?  Because we already have a web API with two DbContexts (both 'normal' in that they inherit from DbContext) connecting to different databases in the same AppDomain - perhaps something that's now fixed, I know they did a lot of work between 1.0.1 and 1.1.0.