# How to apply query types automatically in database first (Scaffold-DbContext) without losing them on re-generation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using `Scaffold-DbContext` to create entities from the database. I also create view entities using [query types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types). Currently I inherit from the generated context, have the self-defined types added as `public DbQuery<TType> TTypes { get; set; }` and in the constructor of the type do basically `public TContext(DbContextOptions<TContext> options): base(options)`, I override also `ModelBuilder` to do `modelBuilder.Query<TType>().ToView("TTypeView", "TSchema");`. To the base scaffolding I've added protected constructor taking non-generic `DbContextOptions` parameters like `protected TBaseContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)`.

This is basically as per instructions at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7533#issuecomment-353669263 and originally I dug it from [How do I implement DbContext inheritance for multiple databases in EF7 / .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829229/how-do-i-implement-dbcontext-inheritance-for-multiple-databases-in-ef7-net-co).

I use inheritance only to add new types to the context. It's a minor annoyance to add the protected constructor while re-scaffolding from the database. Is there a way to avoid this in EF Core 2.1?