# Split database into multiple dbContexts EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have multiple projects that are not related to each other, but in some database look, they have some similarities, like the tables of my authentication system.

I want to use a same base project for all my projects and put all similarities in there, so I don't have to create a base project for all my projects.

I am using EF Core and .Net Core.

I'm wondering if there is any way to split same table among projects into one project and using it in all my projects? or is it a good approach at all?

Project1 DbContext:

```
 public class P1Context : DbContext
 {
     public DbSet<Foo> Foo { get; set; }  
     public DBSet<User> User{ get; set; }
 }
```

Project2 DbContext:

```
public class P2Context : DbContext
{
    public DBSet<Bar> Bar { get; set; }
    public DBSet<User> User { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is:

BaseProject DbContext:

```
 public class BaseContext : DbContext
 {
     public DBSet<User> User { get; set; }
 }
```

Project 1 DbContext:

```
public class P1Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foo { get; set; }  
}
```

Project2 DbContext:

```
public class P2Context : DbContext
{
    public DBSet<Bar> Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a good approach to me

Comment: It is the correct approach however you may face problems similar to mine, here's a solution if you face any problems related to inheriting P1Context from BaseContext (and P2Context from BaseContext as well) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829229.

Comment: This is basically the same approach used by ASP.Net Core Identity -`IdentityDbContext` and related classes. And it's proved to work, so...