# My Context does not inherit from DbContext in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core-3.0

I am trying to keep `BooksContext.cs` file in a folder called **Contexts**.

I have a single `Book` class inside **Entities** folder. Hence, below is the code in `BookContext.cs` file.

I have used the following command at Package Manager Console to enable migrations.

`PM>Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Books.API.Contexts.BooksContext`

But, I'm getting below error:
The type `BooksContext` does not inherit from `DbContext`. The `DbMigrationsConfiguration.ContextType` property must be set to a type that inherits from `DbContext`.

Following the error, I am not sure where and how to set `DbMigrationsConfiguration.ContextType` property

I couldn't get much help from google, and I am not sure what I am missing. Can anyone please help me!

```
namespace Books.API.Contexts
{
    public class BooksContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

        public BooksContext(DbContextOptions<BooksContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            // Tried the accepted answer from below URL, but did not work
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829229/how-do-i-implement-dbcontext-inheritance-for-multiple-databases-in-ef7-net-co
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Author>().HasData(
                new Author
                {
                    Id = Guid.Parse("e4da4ec7-0fe1-46d8-a133-4374ccd54df9"),
                    FirstName = "George",
                    LastName = "RR Martin"
                },
                new Author
                {
                    Id = Guid.Parse("5afd341b-95df-427a-80df-3ed0995a5da6"),
                    FirstName = "Stephen",
                    LastName = "Fry"
                },
                new Author
                {
                    Id = Guid.Parse("4c8bd0d6-14b1-4284-9be1-1cb78c9fc871"),
                    FirstName = "James",
                    LastName = "Elroy"
                },
                new Author
                {
                    Id = Guid.Parse("fc433048-0153-4230-a15b-df1808de27d6"),
                    FirstName = "Douglass",
                    LastName = "Adams"
                }
            );

            modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasData(
                new Book
                {
                    Id = Guid.Parse("92f5d8a9-0141-4bbc-8ee1-61ecdab16cda"),
                    AuthorId = Guid.Parse("e4da4ec7-0fe1-46d8-a133-4374ccd54df9"),
                    Title = "The Winds of Winter",
                    Description = "The book that seems like impossible to write."
                },
                new Book
                {
                    Id = Guid.Parse("1c4ea7c7-f410-4173-b6bd-900f0dd95472"),
                    AuthorId = Guid.Parse("5afd341b-95df-427a-80df-3ed0995a5da6"),
                    Title = "A Game of Throws",
                    Description = "First novel in a song of Ice and Fire"
                },
                new Book
                {
                    Id = Guid.Parse("fd15e575-3d0c-4b92-9b40-63d0f7d58108"),
                    AuthorId = Guid.Parse("4c8bd0d6-14b1-4284-9be1-1cb78c9fc871"),
                    Title = "Mythos",
                    Description = "The Greek myths are amongst the best stories ever told"
                },
                new Book
                {
                    Id = Guid.Parse("d544691c-1a10-4dcd-853a-f7bbd90543ff"),
                    AuthorId = Guid.Parse("fc433048-0153-4230-a15b-df1808de27d6"),
                    Title = "American Tabloid",
                    Description = "It is a 1995 novel"
                }
            );
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a custom `DbContext` class which hides EF's `DbContext`?

Comment: No, I don't have custom `DbContext` class to hide EF's `DbContext`. All I am trying is to create `BooksContext` class inside `Contexts` folder.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I cannot see an obvious mistake in that code. I would say it _does_ inherit DbContext. Have you tried to clean and rebuild the solution?

Comment: `Enable-Migration` is EF6 command and is not needed in EF Core. See [Entity Framework Core tools reference - Package Manager Console in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell) how to install and use EF Core PMC commands.

Comment: @Fildor: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, I tried all the available alternatives, but no lock. My doubt is that: since I have created `DbContext` class inside `Contexts` folder, this problem.

Comment: @Ashokkumar I overlooked that you are on dtonet core. I think Ivan is on to something, there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Small mistake, but good learning for me after spending more than one day painful effort. I hope this will be the good learning for others too.

I have added two NuGet packages of: EntityFramework, and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore which is my mistake.

Just adding NuGet package for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore will do all the required work.

Comment: Not my experience.  As soon as I remove EntityFramework from NuGet I start getting other errors...

Your target project 'MyProject' doesn't reference EntityFramework.

Comment: You must have one reference, that is either EnitityFramework, or Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. Your error states that - Your target project 'MyProject' doesn't reference EntityFramework

Comment: I did have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and I got errors.
What I then did was to remove all EF references, and add them back making sure I had my project selected.  Then it all worked.  I call bugs on Microsoft.

Comment: Sorry, but I could not understand part of your statement. What do you mean by - 'I call bugs on Microsoft'?

Answer (score 1):

In Target Project (that contains your context) just install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` library and if you installed `EntityFramework` (not `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`) library, delete it.
then try

```
enable-migrations -ContextTypeName {path of your dbcontext}
```

for example

```
enable-migrations -ContextTypeName CommonObjects.Entities.Data.ApplicationDbContext
```

it works for me in EF6.