# Are Entity Framework Core commands the same as Entity Framework's?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm just going round in circles here. I'm trying to enable code-first migrations in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project using Entity Framework Core

The `enable-migrations` command doesn't work because it tells me Entity Framework is not installed. If I install it and try to enable migrations, it's telling me there's no `DbContext` because it's not inherited from Core.

I'm specifying exactly where the context is but it won't accept it, so am I supposed to be using different commands for Entity Framework Core?

```
enable-migrations -ContextProjectName <MyProjectName> -contexttypename <PathToContext> -Verbose
```

An answer below makes it seem like having both Entity Framework and Entity Framework Core is the issue, but I've had both and only EF Core installed and neither works: [My Context does not inherit from DbContext in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58619554/my-context-does-not-inherit-from-dbcontext-in-entity-framework-core)

edit: I've come to the conclusion that codefirst migrations are pants.

Comment: EfCore commands are different. Look at the answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47598844/enabling-migrations-in-ef-core) to get started. Also the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) should help you. Once you got used to it Code First works pretty well.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47598844/enabling-migrations-in-ef-core