# How to implement a derived database service with a derived DbContext in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have a class library, with a database access class and a `DbContext` like this:

```
public class DbAccessService : IDatabase
{
     protected IDbContextFactory<DbAccessContext> CtxFactory { get; set; }
     protected readonly ILogger<DbAccessService> Logger;

     public DbAccessService(IDbContextFactory<DbAccessContext> dbContextFactory, ILogger<DbAccessService> logger)
     { 
         Logger = logger;
         CtxFactory = dbContextFactory;
     }
}

public class DbAccessContext : DbContext
{
    public DbAccessContext(DbContextOptions<DbAccessContext> options) : base(options) { }
}
```

I use this in my `program.cs` like this:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDatabase, DbAccessService>();
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<DbAccessContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

This works fine, but I want to extend the service and the context like this, to make some extensions:

```
public class ExtendedDbAccessService : DbAccessService
{
    public ExtendedDbAccessService(IDbContextFactory<ExtendedContext> dbContextFactory, ILogger<ExtendedDbAccessService> logger) 
        : base(dbContextFactory, logger)  { }
}

public class ExtendedContext : DbAccessContext
{
     public ExtendedContext(DbContextOptions<ExtendedContext> options) : base(options) { }
     
     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
     {
         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
         // do some extensions here
     }
 }
```

Of cause this will not work, because the context calling its base class with `base(options)` fails, since it is no `DbAccessContext` but an `ExtendedContext`.

Also the extended service will not work, since `base(dbContextFactory)` is also expecting a `DbAccessContext` and not an `ExtendedContext`.

What am I missing here?

Solved the problem with the context like described here [How to implement cotnext inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829229/how-do-i-implement-dbcontext-inheritance-for-multiple-databases-in-ef7-net-co)

like this:

**public ExtendedContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(ChangeOptionsType(options)) { }**

where ChangeOptions creates a DbAccessContext from ExtendedContext (see the linked question)

But I'm still stuck with the derived service. Is there a way to cast the IDbContextFactory?